# Angular4 - best way to use a carousel for items

Tags: css, angular, rxjs, angular-animations

I'm trying to get working a carousel of items (not images). It is an array of objects of a given type: `IMyObject`. Because I wanted to have one item displayed at a time I did not use `ngFor` for it. Instead, once I did fetch all the objects I would use the `Observable.timer` to loop through the elements:

```
Observable.timer(0, 4000)
          .map((e) => this.myObjects[e % this.myObjects.length])
          .subscribe((item) => {
                     this.currentMyObject= item;
          });
```

So far so good. The HTML I have for it is:

```
<div *ngIf="currentMyObject">¡
    {{currentMyObject.oneOfTheProperties}}
</div>
```

And I can see the element changing every 4 seconds. Now I'd like to introduce an animation and this is where I get stuck. Ideally I'd like to get a fade in / out in place however I think that with the current implementation the animation simply doesn't work because there is no element change if that make sense: the div is already on the page but I don't get any change that would make the animation to trigger, am I right? I have tried different examples from the angular animation documentation (https://angular.io/guide/animations) like flyInOut or I have added a state property to see if that worked with the inactive/active animation but I couldn't get it to work.

Also I'm not sure whether I'm reinventing the wheel here or I'm making things complex. I'm using `ng-carousel` for an image gallery and I don't know if that could be reused here.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found [Angular2-drag-scroll](https://github.com/bfwg/ngx-drag-scroll) on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/6yts3q/angular_carousel_library_is_here/)

[image: Scroll]

Demo site: https://bfwg.github.io/ngx-drag-scroll/

It is also compatible with latest version of Angular(4.3.6)